# Correct usage of regexp syntax in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using a regexp to find any and all patterns denoted by 8 digits separated by an hyphen, as follows:

```
(\d{8}\-\d{8}\)
```

I stuck this in at rubular.com (online regexp editor), and it seemed to work fine. However, when I use it in my Python code I'm getting an error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. I tried taking the backward slashes off the end. But while the error seems to have gone away, the regexp does not find the pattern. I have a string with the following pattern embedded within:

```
output = "... 57867983 - 87995423 ...."
```

and I'm using the following code:

```
include re

regex = re.compile(r"\d{8}\-\d{8}\")

re.search(regex, outuput)
```

The regexp does not return the pattern in the output string. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Here is the actual string that I'm looking to match, as it appears in the returned string:

```
Hash\r\n\t\t01773857 - 90349912\r\n\tWork with
```

Do I need to account for any alphanumeric characters before the 8 digits plus the hyphen that I want to match?

Comment: Try `\d{8}-\d{8}` (remove extraneous backslashes).  Your sample string also has spaces before and after the hyphen

Comment: The dash escaped probably works either way but escaping does ensure it doesn't get treated as a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(\d{8}\s*\-\s*\d{8})')
found = re.search(regex, "11111111-01234567")
print found.group(0)
found = re.search(regex, "22222222 - 01234567")
print found.group(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your last `"` escaped by `\`

You want:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\d{8}\-\d{8}")
```

EDIT - Based on your updated question it looks like you need to account for spaces before your dash:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\d{8}\s*\-\s*\d{8}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You data does not match your pattern:

```
57867983 - 87995423
```

is 8 digits, *followed by a space*, followed by a hyphen, *followed by a space* followed by 8 digits.

So your pattern should be:

```
r"\d{8} - \d{8}"
```

If the spaces are optional, then:

```
r"\d{8} *- *\d{8}"
```

which means "zero or more spaces".  By the way, the hyphen is not a special character outside `[ ]`, so does not need to be escaped.

EDIT:
Here is a more complete example:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"(\d{8}) - (\d{8})")

outuput = "Hash\r\n\t\t01773857 - 90349912\r\n\tWork with"

m = re.search(regex, outuput)

if m: print("Found:",m.groups())
```

Gives:

```
Found: ('01773857', '90349912')
```

Comment: @suffa: you still have spaces around the hyphen!